# Retrieving data from a hash with array values in Perl 6

Tags: raku

I have an array of 3 elements:

```perl6
my @a = <x y z>;
```

Then I make a hash with `Array` values and make `@a`'s contents one of its values:

```perl6
my Array %h;
%h<a> = @a;
```

Later I retrieve this value and assign it to another array:

```perl6
my @A = %h<a>;
```

But what I get in `@A` is not an array of 3 elements, but an array of one element, which is itself an array of 3 elements:

```perl6
say @A;          # [[x y z]]
say @A[0].elems; # 3
```

So, `%h<a>` was `push`ed into `@A`.

Where is the error in my code?

**UPD:** This seems to fix the problem, but doesn't improve my understanding. :)

```perl6
my @A = @(%h<a>);
say @A; [x y z]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason this happens, is that the array `@a` must be put into a container to allow to be stored as a value in a `Hash`.  And something inside a container will remain in the container when being stored into array `@A`.  So, what you need is to get rid of the container when you assign to `@A`.  Your solution is one way of getting rid of the container, but that creates an intermediate `List`, which could become expensive for large arrays.

As I said, you need to get rid of the container.  Fortunately, we have a syntax for that: postfix `<>`:

```
my @a = <a b c>;
my %h = a => @a;
my @b = %h<a><>;  # <-- note the <> here
dd @b;    # Array @b = ["a", "b", "c"]
```

This would be the most efficient way if you really want `@b` to be mutable.  Alternately, if you want `@b` to be just an alias of the original `@a`, you could also bind:

```
my @a = <a b c>;
my %h = a => @a;
my @b := %h<a>;  # <-- note the := here
dd @b;    # Array @a = ["a", "b", "c"]
```

Note that the `dd` output now shows `@a` as the name, as it now really is the same as `@a`: any changes to `@a` will now also show in `@b` and vice-versa.  Which would be ok if you're not changing them anyway.  If that's true in your situation, then this would be the most efficient way of doing this, both CPU-wise as well as memory-wise.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is there a page about postfix `<>` in the docs?

Comment: https://docs.perl6.org/language/containers#Flattening,_items_and_containers has some info on it, but it could maybe be improved.  If you think so, please create a documentation issue for it: https://github.com/perl6/doc/issues